# Pycharm keyboard shortcut box disruptive

Tags: pycharm

I'm not sure how I turned on this mode but whenever I click a button in  PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.2, a flashing red box appears with the keyboard shortcut for that button. It is very disruptive especially while using the debugger.

How can I disable this? See image -> [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58sSf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Key Promoter` plugin, you can disable it in `File - Settings - Plugins`.